# Is there a way to get these two array Id in this reactjs code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am wondering if there is a way to get around this: So, I am building a blog application using node.js, Mongodb and react.js.
I added comment feature and I added reply to comments feature. Everything works well so far. My challenge is that I am using populate() method of mongodb which deals with ref id. Comment model has an array of replies that is referencing reply model. Everything is working well as I tested in postman. The challenge is implementing this in reactjs. I want to be able to delete each reply. I already implemented the update feature in react, but the delete feature needs two ids. That is what I don't know how to get. My route path is like this in node.js:

```
router.delete("/posts/:id/comments/:commentId/reply/:replyId", async (req, res) =>{
  //my codes here
 }
```

As you can see, I have post id, commentId and replyId. It is easy to copy and paste them in postman and test your logic. But it is a bit tricky with react.js.

I have a comment component where I rendered the comments array via map() method. You know, each has an array of replies. So, I mapped the replies as well. Now, to delete any reply, I need the post id, comment id and reply id. How do I get the comment id since the delete button is coming from the replies array? I can only fetch the replies id, but can't fetch the comment id. Have a look at my react code setup.

comments is the array of comments and in it, you have replies. Replies is an array of replies. I have to map into replies to display each replies.

```
 return (
          <div className="comment">
           <h5 className='users-comment'>Users comments</h5>
            {comments.map((singleComment, index)=>{
               // console.log(singleComment)
                const {author, commentdescription, _id, createdAt, replies} = singleComment
                
                return(
               <div className='displayed-comments'key={_id}>
                          <p className="comment-content"> {singleComment.commentdescription}</p>
                     </div>
                         )
                   
                      //replies are returned here

                   {replies.map((singleReply) =>{
                     const {_id, author, createdAt, replycomment} = singleReply
                        return(
                               <div className='comment-div' key={_id} >

                                    <i className={isLoading? "cursor-not-allowed singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt":"singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt" }   
                                    onClick={()=> handleDeleteComment(_id)}
                                                                 ></i>
                                  <p className="comment-content">{replycomment}</p> 
                                   </div>
                                )
```

handleDeleteComment(_id) is a delete button that grabbed the id of the replies array individually. But to delete each replies, I need also need the id coming from the comments array that I mapped before the replies array.

Here is my delete logic in react:

```
//handle delete reply commmet

 const handleDeleteComment = async (id)=>{
 try{
            await axios.delete(`/posts/${path}/comments/${id}/reply${id}`, {data: {author:  user._id}});
              window.location.replace("/")
    }catch(err){

    }

 }
```

I have the post id known as ${path}, I have the reply id but the specific comment id is what I can't seem to get. Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You asked a question as hard as possible

Comment: Yea, seems hard. I can avoid this route path in node.js which will also help me to avoid looking for the comment id in react. I can use this path in node.js router.put("/:id", async (req, res) =>{ //logicc here}. The problem is that it will delete but the referenced id made in comment model will not be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your `handleDeleteComment`, pass two arguments instead of one, `comment_id` and `reply_id`.

```
//handle delete reply commmet
const handleDeleteComment = async (comment_id, reply_id) => {
  try{
     await axios.delete(`/posts/${path}/comments/${comment_id}/reply/${reply_id}`, {data: {author:  user._id}});
     history.replace("/") // See the next point
   } catch(err){
     
   }
}
```

2. Use `history.replace("/")` instead of `window.location.replace("/")` because the former navigates to the new page without making a new HTTP call to the server where as the latter does that.

```
// imports
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
...

function MyComponent(props){
  // Creating the history object
  const history = useHistory();
  
  // Other Component logic
  
}
```

3. On destructuring  `singleComment`, do this instead

```
const {author, commentdescription, _id: comment_id, createdAt, replies} = singleComment
```

Now you have `comment_id` for `comment` and `_id` for the reply. Just call your  `handleDelete` function as

```
onClick={()=> handleDeleteComment(comment_id, _id)}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. This solved my problem. I learnt something new here. Thank you so very much

Comment: I wanted to ask, using useHistory there and window.reload() which is better?